# AS3 Socket ProcessEvent.SOCKET_DATA seems not triggered

Tags: actionscript-3, sockets

We use AS3 Event:ProcessEvent.SOCKET_DATA to listen for socket data.
So this is my AS3 code for socket data handle.

```
private function packetHandler( e:ProgressEvent ):void
    {
        while( m_socket.bytesAvailable && m_socket.bytesAvailable >= pLen )
        {
            //pLen means the packet length
            //pLen init is zero
            if( pLen == 0 )
            {
                //PACKET_LEN stands for the solid length of one packet
                //PACKET_LEN = HEAD_LEN + 4
                //the 4 means an unsigned int which means the packet content length
                if( m_socket.bytesAvailable > PACKET_LEN )
                {
                    m_socket.readBytes(  headByteBuffer, 0, HEAD_LEN );
                    headByteBuffer.clear();
                    pLen = m_socket.readUnsignedInt() + 4;
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            //recieved a whole packet now handle it
            else
            {
                var newPacket:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
                
                newPacket.endian = Endian.LITTLE_ENDIAN;
                m_socket.readBytes( newPacket, 0, pLen );
                
                parasMsg( newPacket, pLen-4 );
                pLen = 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

**A whole packet can be described in this picture:**
[image: http://wuzhiwei.net/problems/packet.gif]

**My Problem is: When there has one incomplete packet received in Flash and triggered the handle.
But the left part of the packet will never trigger the handle and it seems like that the left part of the packet has lost!!!**

I used a capture tool, find that the tcp packet is ok, but why the left part doesn't trigger the event again?

You can get more debug information below. Thank you!

**This is my log:**

- byteava means bytesAvailable of m_socket

> ==>sendPacket: {"rangeID":"1","uid":"145962","serviceType":"copyscene","cmd":"CopySceneMoveAsk","pathPoint":[{"col":7,"row":6},{"col":7,"row":5},{"col":7,"row":4},{"col":7,"row":3},{"col":6,"row":3}],"sn":"79","smallPathPoint":[[22,19],[22,18],[22,17],[22,16],[22,15],[22,14],[22,13],[21,13],[21,12],[21,11],[20,11],[20,10]]}, bytesLoaded = 463
>
> ProgressEvent Triggered!0 socket byteava = 373 evt loaded:373 evt total:0 evt:[ProgressEvent type="socketData" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 bytesLoaded=373 bytesTotal=0]
>
> Find a packet from socket, pLen=288 socket byteava = 276
>
> ProgressEvent Triggered!288 socket byteava = 441 evt loaded:165 evt total:0 evt:[ProgressEvent type="socketData" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 bytesLoaded=165 bytesTotal=0]
>
> Start to Read a packet to buffer, pLen=288 socket byteava = 441
>
> whole packet content: Readed a packet to buffer, pLen=288 socket byteava = 153
>
> Server packet content byte buffer ava:288 len：288 pos: 0
>
> Server Paras Data : data len: 284 data content: {"cmd":"CopySceneMoveNotify","gtcmd":"108","layer":"1","pathPoint":[{"col":7,"row":6},{"col":7,"row":5},{"col":7,"row":4},{"col":7,"row":3},{"col":6,"row":3}],"smallPathPoint":[[22,19],[22,18],[22,17],[22,16],[22,15],[22,14],[22,13],[21,13],[21,12],[21,11],[20,11],[20,10]HTTP/1.1 200

**`_[20,10]HTTP/1.1 200_` This is what went wrong!! The incomplete packet cat with another packet's header.**

**Here is the capture of the TCP connections:**
[image: http://wuzhiwei.net/problems/captured_packets.jpg]

Hope you can **vote it up** so that I can put my pictures of this question on!

My English is not very good, hope you can understand what I mean.
Thank you!

Comment: Why the type of e is ProgressEvent?

Comment: ProgressEvent.SOCKET_DATA

Comment: I'm almost sure that the problem is in packetHandler and especially  in while usage. My games are server/client and communication is via socket and never have a problem like this. Also I'm almost if you change m_socket.readBytes( newPacket, 0, pLen ); to m_socket.readBytes( newPacket, 0, m_socket.bytesAvailable ); you will get the message without HTTP/1.1 200_

Comment: But what shows me is that the ProgressEvent.SOCKET_DATA doesn't triggered( so it will not enter while loop), and the incomplete part of a packet seems lost because it cat with another packet's header.

Comment: the bytesAvailable in m_socket sometimes can't be a whole packet, so if I receive half of a packet I will leave the data in socket buffer. And when a whole packet received I will handle the packet and read the packet from the socket buffer.

Comment: yas, and bytesAvailable  says how many bytes you can read. When you receive a second packet bytesAvailable will be the number of bytes left from previous packet plus bytes from the second.

Comment: So the question is I lost some data. You can see in the first Event trigger, I receive only 276 bytes of the packet content which whole length should be 288. But the next Event trigger bring me a whole new packet seems like that the 8 bytes of the pre packet is lost!

Comment: Problem might be solved. Please see the update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem should caused by the packet's solid header.

Below is the 93 bytes solid header of a packet.

```
private static const HTTP_RESPONSE_CONTENT : String = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK \r\n"
        + "Connection: keep-alive \r\n"
        + "Content-Length: 280 \r\n"
        + "Content-Type: text/html \r\n\r\n";
```

This header will be in every packet's header, which AS3 could treat it to a `http` and might cut the flow with `Content-Length: 280`. So the left part of the 280 bytes will never trigger the SOCKET_DATA event.

When I remove this header, it's ok now.

Answer (score 0):

The Socket's event  flash.events.ProgressEvent.SOCKET_DATA will fire when you receive the data  at this point you can get the received bytes ( check .bytesAvailable ). When the msg is split into multiple packages you will receive event for each packet. 
In your case maybe the pLen have wrong value when check  m_socket.bytesAvailable >= pLen.

I assume you send the msg size in the begging of the message ( in this case you can check if the whole msg is received ). In this case you must have a class member (ByteArray ) as buffer that holds a received bytes. When new data come you must copy the new bytes to this member and than check if you receive whole msg. If buffer contains whole msg than remove the msg from it.
In general your event handler must looks like this:

```
protected function onSocketData( pEvt: Event ): void
{
    try
{
       if ( 0 < pEvt.target.bytesAvailable )
       {
    var byteStream: ByteArray = new ByteArray();            
    pEvt.target.readBytes( byteStream, 0, Socket( pEvt.target ).bytesAvailable );
    // Append readed data to your buffer

    do 
    {
        //Check if you have enough bytes to read whole msg and execute it
                    //do..while because maybe it can be more than one msg in buffer

    }
    while ( null != msgContent );
    }
}
catch ( exc )
{

}
```

}

Comment: The pLen is OK. And we can use the socket's own buffer to do so.

Comment: The problem is the left of one whole packet doesn't triggered the SOCKET_DATA event. I'll show you soon.